# cannot correctly use DataFrame.Apply

Tags: python, static, pandas, apply, dataframe

I have the following problem, I have a Panda data frame and I want to process each row ny using the apply method. Each row should be processed by using a function (static method) within the same class..

```
@staticmethod
def my_func(s, e, a):
(...)


res = myDataFrame.apply(self.my_func, 0, s, e, a)
```

s, e and a are NxM dataframes.
Now the error I get is the following:

> TypeError: my_func() takes exactly 3 arguments (11 given)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

May this be the correct solution?

```
res = myDataFrame.apply(lambda x: class.my_func(x, s, e, a), axis=0)
```